# How can create a webapplication in dotnetnuke framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetopenauth

I am very new to dotnetnuke. and want to know. steps to create and build a webapplication in dotnetnuke.

how can we add module using dotnetnuke.

how can we handle database in sqlsever 2005 or later on it.

Want to know briefly and understanding explanation.

Comment: This is a very general question; I would suggest trying the dotnetnuke website as a resource for learning about it. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to fallowing video 
http://video.google.com/videosearch?hl=en&source=hp&q=dnn+tutorial&oq=dnn&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=aUlpS-anJs-HkAWw3pS2DQ&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CBkQqwQwAw#

Comment: This video is no longer available, please update the link ! thank you